# Augmented Frequency on 20newsgroup dataset.TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, gensim

I am working on the 20newsgroup dataset using Python. After using CountVectorizer on it and then using the gensim api for augmented term frequency. I tried fitting it but am getting this error.

Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(max_features=2000)
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
twenty_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', shuffle=True)
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(twenty_train.data)
from gensim.sklearn_api import TfIdfTransformer
model = TfIdfTransformer(smartirs='atn')
tfidf_aug = model.fit_transform(X_train_counts())
```

After running the above code I get this error:

`TypeError: sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0]`

After using getnz() at the end like this.

```
tfidf_aug = model.fit_transform(X_train_counts().getnnz())
```

I get this error:

`TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 1):

The input for TfidfTransformer has to be iterator of (int,int) as mentioned [here](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/sklearn_api/tfidf.py#L104). Hence you have to process the sparse matrix, before it to gensim model.

Try this

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
twenty_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', shuffle=True)
from gensim.sklearn_api import TfIdfTransformer

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(max_features=2000)

X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(twenty_train.data)

model = TfIdfTransformer(smartirs='atn')
tfidf_aug = model.fit_transform([[(i,j) for i,j in zip(a.data,a.indices)] for a in X_train_counts ])
```